cpanel user trying to run a node script from php
cpanel user is trying to run nodejs script from php - keeps running into 126 and 127 and 2 errors... Terminal works, but calling the same nodejs script from php does not.
We have tried installing it locally and also globally WHM.
Is such an operation possible from CPanel? What are the permissions/settings/configs?
